# AsyncHttpWebRequest (web page title retrieve program)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to create a program that will retrieve page titles given a url. I've written code that works when I'm not using a AsyncCallback, but when I use a AsyncCallback the code doesn't seem to work.

```
public void GetWebPageTitle(string URL)
{
    // make request for web page
    HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    myWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    myWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), myWebRequest);
    zConsole.WriteLine("Beginning HttpWebRequest for: " + URL);
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    zConsole.WriteLine("...");
    string title = "Unknown";

    //Code under here doesnt get extcuted

    HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)((HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result);
    StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string source = "";            
    source = myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
    myWebResponse.Close();
    title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
    zConsole.WriteLine(title);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does, "the code doesn't seem to work" mean? Is the `FinishWebRequest` method ever called? Does it write an empty title?

Comment: @jimMischel after testing my program some more i realized FinishWebRequest method never gets called (i got confused before because VS stopped at a breakpoint in the FinishWebRequest method). As you can tell I'm very new to async and threading.

Comment: @zaza The good is near-standard example of the FinishWebRequest method. Your regex for extracting title looks okay too. Can you specify the error you are getting? Maybe add the output/error to your answer?

Comment: @Abbas The problem is that the FinishWebRequest method never gets called

Comment: I'm a little confused. If Visual Studio stopped at a breakpoint in the `FinishWebRequest` method, then the method must have been called. That said, you might consider using the `WebClient` class and `DownloadStringAsync`. That uses an event-oriented interface, which is easier to use than `HttpWebRequest`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventhandler.aspx for an example.

Comment: @JimMischel yea its a little strange, my breakpoint stops at the the first line of the 'FinishWebRequest' method but not on any other breakpoints in the method. i'll just use the 'WebClient' its a lot easier to use and i dont really need the control that 'HttpWebRequest' offers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is, your program ends, before async result is returned.
The main thread after doing Console.Writeline dies.

Rest looks okay. BeginGetResponse at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Put a try/catch block around the code inside the callback and see if anything in there is throwing an exception.

Otherwise some more details would be useful. When you say that the code doesn't get executed are you actually stepping through the code/using breakpoints or are you assuming this is the case based on your console output? Is this request being made from the main window thread of your application?